# Detect Empty Pixel From File

Tags: java, image-processing, alpha, is-empty

For full Project check repo here. Feel free to clone and run. Note the test images
https://github.com/AshGale/Image2RGBA

When Reading in a PNG that has sections shown as empty(hashed) in GIMP, the values read into the program are [0,0,0,255](Red, Green, Blue, Alpha). I expect the empty bit to have Alpha 0 therefore fully empty [0,0,0,0]. However the value is [0,0,0,255] witch is also Full Black.

1. Question, how can I check in java if a pixel is completely empty, ie hashed in gimp.
2. how can i then write this to an image file with a bufferedImage.
3. Should the alpha value be 0 for an image with empty as shown in image? please suggest way to read in file or file format.

   //Code Extract See Git for full code

...

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageHeight; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < imageWidth; j++) {

    individualPixel = new Color(buffImage.getRGB(j, i));

    //TODO find a way to detect a empty pixel an keep perfect black
    if(individualPixel.getRed() == 0 
            && individualPixel.getGreen() == 0
            && individualPixel.getBlue() ==0
            ) {                             

        //set pixel at location to empty
        buffRed.setRGB(j, i, getIntFromColor(0, 0, 0, 0));
        buffGreen.setRGB(j, i, getIntFromColor(0, 0, 0, 0));
        buffBlue.setRGB(j, i, getIntFromColor(0, 0, 0, 0));
    }else {
        // RED
        tempPixel = new Color(individualPixel.getRed(), 0, 0, individualPixel.getAlpha());
        buffRed.setRGB(j, i, getIntFromColor(tempPixel.getRed(), 0, 0, tempPixel.getAlpha()));

        // GREEN

        // BLUE
    }
```

...

```
ImageIO.write(buffRed, "png", redImg);
```

[image]

Comment: "values red into the program are [0,0,0,255]" - I assume you mean `[255,0,0,255]`.

Comment: "how can I check in java if a pixel is completely empty" - You basically answered this yourself: "I expect the empty bit to have Alpha 0" - you just need to read the alpha channel from the file and check its value. The `getRGB()` method won't help you there so check out `getAlphaRaster()` etc. - as is often the case the `JavaDoc` and the many tutorials on the internet are your friends here (for how to write that image to a file too).

Comment: sorry i meant READ.
I will have a look into getAlphaRaster() thanks. 
I have writing a file, but added just in case there is special way when dealing with alpha

Comment: @Thomas I tried that, but it didn't seem to help. The only thing it did was make the alpha a 0 value instead of a 255 value for all pixels
WritableRaster imageRaster = buffImage.getAlphaRaster();
     int[] pixel = new int[4];
     int alpha = 0;
     
     for (int i = 0; i < imageHeight; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < imageWidth; j++) {

       individualPixel = new Color(buffImage.getRGB(j, i));
       
       imageRaster.getPixel(j, i, pixel);
       alpha = pixel[3];
       
       if(alpha != 0)

Comment: Hmm, the code you posted in your comment is hard to read to spotting errors isn't easy. Assuming there are none it might be a matter of the color/pixel format specified when reading the image. According to the docs the default format would be ARGB so the alpha channel should be at index 0.

Comment: @Thomas yes, sorry about that, i just put it there for a rough idea of what i was doing. Feel free to see full version at https://github.com/AshGale/Image2RGBA
I have commented out the Raster bit for now. i'll try again and see if i missed something. . . i'm using png that says its supports alpha, maybe i'll try BMP

Comment: BMP doesn't support alpha so keep using PNG. What I meant is how you specify the color format when reading the image, i.e. you read the pixels into an in-memory representation of the image (`BufferedImage`) which has its own layout. The codecs that read the image will convert the file's data into that internal layout (e.g. by decompressing, color space conversione etc.) and any data that's not required will be ignored while missing data might be filled with default values - thus it depends on how the `BufferedImage` is configured.

Comment: @Thomas :) i got it sorted out in the end. The tutorial i used for Raster idicated alpha at the end 3, not start 0. once i changed the index it worked as expected. I have put a more detailed solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem in your original code is simply this line:

```
individualPixel = new Color(buffImage.getRGB(j, i));
```

This `Color` constructor effectively discards the alpha component. JavaDoc says (emphasis mine):

> Creates an *opaque* sRGB color with the specified combined RGB value [...] Alpha is defaulted to 255.

Instead it should be:

```
individualPixel = new Color(buffImage.getRGB(j, i), true); // hasAlpha = true
```

This constructors JavaDoc says:

> Creates an sRGB color with the specified combined RGBA value [...] If the `hasalpha` argument is `false`, alpha is defaulted to 255.

You shouldn't really have to use the alpha raster (not all `BufferedImage`s have one) to achieve this, and avoiding it is both simpler and more compatible.

Finally, the R, G and B values of a fully transparent pixel doesn't really matter. So testing whether it is all black may be a too strict check (although it does seem to work fine for your input image).

PS: I think a more precise terminology would be "transparent", instead of "empty".

Answer (score 0):

This is the worked example, you can also see full at my github in question.
Thankyou to Thomas who sujested the use of getAlphaRaster()

```
// get RGB from image
BufferedImage buffImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

try {
    buffImage = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
}

int imageHeight = buffImage.getHeight();
int imageWidth = buffImage.getWidth();
Color individualPixel = null;
Color tempPixel = null;

BufferedImage buffRed = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
BufferedImage buffGreen = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
BufferedImage buffBlue = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

WritableRaster imageRaster = buffImage.getAlphaRaster();
int[] pixel = new int[4];
int alpha = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < imageHeight; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < imageWidth; j++) {

        individualPixel = new Color(buffImage.getRGB(j, i));

        imageRaster.getPixel(j, i, pixel);
        alpha = pixel[0];//return 0 for empty

        //if(individualPixel.getAlpha() <255 || alpha >0)
            System.out.println(j + "," + i + " : " + individualPixel.getAlpha()+ "-"+alpha+ " =>" +
                    pixel[0] + " " + pixel[1] + " " + pixel[2] + " " + pixel[3]);

        //TODO find a way to detect a empty pixel an keep perfect black
        if(individualPixel.getRed() == 0 
                && individualPixel.getGreen() == 0
                && individualPixel.getBlue() ==0
                & alpha == 0) {                             

            //set pixel at location to empty
            buffRed.setRGB(j, i, getIntFromColor(0, 0, 0, 0));
            buffGreen.setRGB(j, i, getIntFromColor(0, 0, 0, 0));
            buffBlue.setRGB(j, i, getIntFromColor(0, 0, 0, 0));
        }else {
            // RED
            tempPixel = new Color(individualPixel.getRed(), 0, 0, individualPixel.getAlpha());
            buffRed.setRGB(j, i, getIntFromColor(tempPixel.getRed(), 0, 0, tempPixel.getAlpha()));

            // GREEN
            tempPixel = new Color(0, individualPixel.getGreen(), 0, individualPixel.getAlpha());
            buffGreen.setRGB(j, i, getIntFromColor(0, tempPixel.getGreen(), 0, tempPixel.getAlpha()));

            // BLUE
            tempPixel = new Color(0, 0, individualPixel.getBlue(), individualPixel.getAlpha());
            buffBlue.setRGB(j, i, getIntFromColor(0, 0, tempPixel.getBlue(), tempPixel.getAlpha()));
        }
    }   
    System.out.println("");                 
}

// Save Images to path of selected file
try {
    ImageIO.write(buffRed, "png", redImg);
    ImageIO.write(buffGreen, "png", greenImg);
    ImageIO.write(buffBlue, "png", blueImg);
} catch (IOException e) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to create RGB files");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```